# ¿Por qué en mi página aparece el icono de YouTube?

Tags: html, html5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Titulo de la página</title>
 </head>
```

Aca se puede ver que no tengo ninguna etiqueta link en la que inserte un icono. Cabe destacar que una vez copie todo el HTML de Youtube y lo pegue en mi página, y desde ese entonces tengo ese icono y nunca lo pude sacar.

Comment: Siempre es peligroso copiar y pegar nada más.
Debes reescribir tu código para que esté limpio

Comment: Entiendo, en realidad quise experimentar que pasaba, ¿hay alguna solución para esto?

Comment: es el cache de favicons, con definir uno y refresh debería cambiar. si no cambia fijate en `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` o `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Favicons` o `~/.config/chromium/Default/Favicons` según el OS de ahí podes borrar y al reiniciar el navegador los carga de nuevo

Comment: Suponía que era algo del caché, pero no sabia como borrarlo. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como te han comentado antes, es por caché del navegador.

Puedes especificar un favicon introduciendo este código en el bloque head

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución. Mira [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).